# horizontal fence DIY?

Tags: fence, horizontal

seeing if yall could advise at all.

I'm on the fence about building a fence vs paying a contractor. I've got quotes from $3600-$4600 or I could buy materials and do the labor myself for about $1500-$1800. I've never built a fence before.

Question 1:
Any advice about what to do around the power pole in the corner? angle? zigzag?
If I angle it, that long section will be about 12' long, so I'd need a post in the middle.

Question 2:
how to do the step down from 6' privacy fence to short 4' tall golf course fence? Just one big drop?

Question 3:
how do I do the corners when its not 90degrees? do I need to slightly miter the edge of the boards?

In the drawing, everything except the gate and the angled is 8'sections.
I've measured it all out.

- an 11' gate section (haven't decided how to do this yet)
- an 88' long section along neighbor's line.
- an 48' long section along the golf course

[image: options]

[image: stepdown?]

[image: survey w/ property lines]

[image: brick wall]

[image: survey]

Comment: Why not just turn 90 degrees from the neighbor side and take it straight across to the tree?  The fence line would then run roughly parallel to the golf course line. [pic](https://imgur.com/5zmYVSe)

Comment: Before you do anything, make very sure you know where the property lines are and if there is a specific easement for that power pole.  Also, some areas have codes on how a fence is to be constructed.  A fence company would know all that, but you may not.  You can certainly DIY this, but make sure you know all the rules or you'll have to DIY undo it too.

Comment: @JPhi1618 It looks to me like the base image was pulled from his county's public property records and they are usually pretty accurate (source: I develop software for such tax offices).  Still might be a good idea to get an inspector/surveyor to verify.

Comment: You do know that this is a back breaking job... right?? I'm just saying this because I've known people to just throw their hands up in the air after a few weeks and get a contractor.

Comment: @Steve-o169, good point. Sorry, I mis drew the lines in the first two cartoons. I edited OP to include survey and a photo. original brick wall fell down. it ran across the golf course boundary to a tree. Then a short picket fence was made on the other side of tree to finish off the fence line.

Comment: @Steve-o169, yea, I've got the property survey. The fence line is kinda fucked...they build this brick wall inside the property line and there's a big tree in the way that keeps it from connecting the fence line across it.

Comment: @JACK, yea, that's kinda what I'm asking about. is the $3000 worth the DIY labor?

Comment: I think it's worth it. I'm paying to have someone rip up asphalt and put pavers down in my driveway... some jobs are just worth it.

Comment: The original wall "fell down"? Yikes. Worth $3K to have someone else do it? Depends--how young and strong you are and how much time you have on your hands? I wouldn't consider DIY today, but 20 yrs ago, I wouldn't have considered NOT DIY. Good luck